# How to right align columns of DataTable in R Shiny?

Tags: jquery, r, datatables, shiny

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12527707/giving-right-align-to-numeric-data-in-datatables) I gather we should define an `alignRight` CSS class with the desired alignment:

```
# ui.R
sidebarLayout(...,
    mainPanel(
        tags$head(
            tags$style(".alignRight { align: right; }", media = "all", type = "text/css")
        ),
        ...     # content with call to dataTableOutput("myTable")
    )
)
```

and then when creating the DataTable, use the [`aoColumnDefs`](http://datatables.net/usage/columns) option to set class of the desired columns to `alignRight`:

```
# server.R
shinyServer(
    function(input, output) {...
        output$myTable <- renderDataTable(...,
            options = list(
                aoColumnDefs = '[{"aTargets": [7, 9, 10], "sClass": "alignRight"}]'
            )
        )
    }
)
```

However, this has had no effect on my DataTable, when remains left aligned for all columns. I thought a simple alignment issue would be easy to sort out, but after many hours, apparently not so. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
library(shiny)

runApp(list(
  ui = basicPage(
    tags$head(tags$style(".table .alignRight {color: blue; text-align:right;}")),
    h2('The mtcars data'),
    dataTableOutput('mytable')
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$mytable = renderDataTable({
      mtcars
    }, options =list(aoColumnDefs = list(list(sClass="alignRight",aTargets=c(list(3),list(4),list(5))))  ))
  }
))
```

worked for me and might help you model the CSS right for your situation. I only used `blue` since it helps show if other parts of the `td` formatting are working even if one might not be.

Comment: Great - thanks! However, the column headings also become right-aligned and clash with the little sort icon - is there any way to fix this? Cheers.

Comment: prbly have to twiddle the CSS a bit. I forget if `DataTables` use `thead` by default, but if they do, it's a matter of adding a CSS to handle that case. I'll see if I can give it a go a bit later.

Comment: How does the new format work? This doesn't seem to work.


options =list(columnDefs = list(list(class="right",aTargets=c(list(3),list(4),list(5)))))

Answer (score 8):

The following works fine with no custom class definition:

```
option=list(columnDefs=list(list(targets=3:5, class="dt-right")))
```